# Flutter GetX: the value passed in arguments is null on second page

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-getx

When navigating from one page to another using GetX Flutter, the arguments passed from the first page are not received on the second page.

First Controller:

```
class LoginController extends GetxController {
  var _loading = false.obs;

  get loading => _loading.value;

  set loading(value) {
    _loading.value = value;
  }

  var _loginResponse = LoginResponse().obs;

  late TextEditingController emailController, passwordController;

  @override
  void onInit() {
    super.onInit();
    emailController = TextEditingController();
    passwordController = TextEditingController();
  }

  @override
  void onReady() {
    super.onReady();
  }

  @override
  void onClose() {
    super.onClose();
    emailController.dispose();
    passwordController.dispose();
  }

  Future<void> loginCall(
      {required String email, required String password}) async {

 
    if (!GetUtils.isEmail(email)) {
      Get.snackbar('Invalid email', 'Please enter valid email',
          snackPosition: SnackPosition.BOTTOM);
      return;
    }

    if (password.length < 8) {
      Get.snackbar('Invalid password', 'Minimum 8 chars',
          snackPosition: SnackPosition.BOTTOM);
      return;
    }

    _loading.value = true;

    var result =
        await NetworkRequest.loginCall(email: email, password: password);

    result != null
        ? _loginResponse.value = result
        : Get.snackbar(
            'Something went wrong', 'Hold back and try again after sometime.',
            snackPosition: SnackPosition.BOTTOM);

    if(_loginResponse.value.responseCode == 1) {

      **Get.offAll(GoogleAuthenticationScreen(), arguments: _loginResponse.value.responseData!.session.toString());**
    }

    _loading.value = false;

  }
}
```

Second Controller:

```
class GoogleAuthenticationController extends GetxController {
  var _loading = false.obs;
  late TextEditingController pinController;
  var _authResponse = GoogleTwoFactorResponse().obs;

  @override
  void onInit() {
    super.onInit();
    pinController = TextEditingController();
    var session = Get.arguments.toString();
    twoFactorCall(token: session);
  }

  @override
  void onClose() {
    super.onClose();
    pinController.dispose();
  }

  Future<void> twoFactorCall({required String token}) async {
    _loading.value = true;

    var result = await NetworkRequest.googleAuthentication(token: token);

    result != null
        ? _authResponse.value = result
        : Get.snackbar(
            'Something went wrong', 'Hold back and try again after sometime.',
            snackPosition: SnackPosition.BOTTOM);

    Get.snackbar(result!.responseMessage!, "",
        snackPosition: SnackPosition.BOTTOM);

    _loading.value = false;
  }
}
```

**Getx Version  get: ^4.3.8**

Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.2, on macOS 11.4 20F71 darwin-x64, locale en-IN)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 4.1)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)

• No issues found!

Comment: are you trying to take values inside controller cause they are not pushed in the stack?. You should take them in the Authentication Screen and later set it on the screens init method.

Comment: Yes, I have updated the code please let me know

Comment: you will only be able to access those arguments here in GoogleAuthenticationScreen() code.

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
 final session = Get.arguments;
```

outside of onInIt method. hope it will work

Answer (score -1):

Yes, I have an answer. I have used pass arguments from one class to another, show code below.

Here `LoginController` use for `LoginScreen` class

```
class LoginController extends GetxController
{
  passArguments()
  {
    Get.offAll(GoogleAuthenticationScreen(),arguments: "passData1");
    //For pass multiple arguments
    Get.offAll(GoogleAuthenticationScreen(),arguments:["passData1","passData2","passData3"]);
  }
}
```

Here your argument pass in `GoogleAuthenticationScreen`. And now you have to pass the argument from `GoogleAuthenticationScreen` to `GoogleAuthenticationController`.

```
class GoogleAuthenticationScreen extends StatelessWidget 
{
  GoogleAuthenticationController googleAuthenticationController = Get.put(GoogleAuthenticationController());

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if(Get.arguments != null){
       //for one value
      googleAuthenticationController.arguments1.value = Get.arguments;
      //for multiple value
      googleAuthenticationController.arguments1.value = Get.arguments[0...1];
    }
    return Container();
  }
}

class GoogleAuthenticationController extends GetxController
{
  //here my value as a string data type
  var arguments1 = "".obs;
}
```

Try this way.

Comment: Hello, here i have updated it and. now it is working i have already tested. thank you.